# VSCode Extension - How do i make a "select" in view command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image]

I can find many examples having simple button-like action, I'de like to know if this kind of view is possible via the vscode api.

Comment: create a `WebviewView` and use whatever HTML/JS/CSS framework you like, Angular, Vue, React, Svelte, .....

Comment: Nah. the menu should contribute to `menu/title`.

Comment: the API available to the VSC developers is much richer than that to the extension developers of the TreeView, with WebviewView you can now do anything you like